# How to answer "Where are traveling from/coming from" at US airport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, interview

If I'm from Bulgaria and my first flight is from Bulgaria to Germany, and after a few hours second flight is from Germany to the US airport. In that case what should I answer to the US custom officer if they ask where I'm coming from/traveling from? Should I say Bulgaria, or Germany?

Comment: I think you mean Immigration Officer. Customs officers are concerned with illegal/excess items in your baggage.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no trick here, and this isn't a paper form where you only get one chance to enter a single word answer. I typically answer with the country I have spent my trip in (or live in) first, and then add that I transited in another. So for your case:

> Sofia, with a change of planes in Munich

(I almost always answer with cities rather than countries, it's an old habit of mine, and no customs officer has ever had a problem with it.)

Lying to customs officers is very bad. So just answering literally with the place you changed planes might be seen as trying to hide your origin. Answering with only your origin, if the officer knows there are no direct flights, might be seen as trying to hide your transit. Giving both pieces of information is easy and much safer than only giving either one.

Comment: Thanks, of course I do not have any intention to lie, I was just not sure if they ask what flight I am coming from, or if they ask where I'm actually from. But thank you, its clear now.

Comment: "So just answering literally with the place you changed planes might be seen as trying to hide your origin" -- is there any known precedent for someone being punished for this scenario? "Answering with only your origin, if the officer knows there are no direct flights, might be seen as trying to hide your transit" -- is there any known precedent for someone being punished for this scenario? If the answer is yes to both, that would presumably enable some interesting legal arguments that CBP can't have it both ways, and has to make up its mind on which answer it wants.

Comment: @nanoman Unfortunately, the courts are very often quite happy to let law enforcement have it both ways.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer +1. I would typically grunt something like "Sofia via Munich". Or if the connection was a stopover for a couple days - "from Munich, today".

Comment: @nanoman "punished" is a very fluid concept. The officer might feel suspicious, and start asking you sharper questions, resulting in nothing more than 3 extra questions before you were let in. You might be sent to secondary, or be searched. You might be made to feel nervous or uncomfortable. Are these punishments? I don't intend to suggest you'll be charged and jailed as a result of a single word answer. But there are still reasons to avoid that.

Comment: @nanoman people are heckled by immigration officers for nothing objective on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

On your question you wrote: **customs officer**, so your question is about customs. So practically where you embarked your baggage.

Technically it is about where you previously cleared customs (which could be various places), but mostly irrelevant for air travelers.

So, in your case, you can write *Sofia, Bulgaria* (if you started there) or *Bulgaria* or also just *European Union*.

Note: I would prefer the most specific item, because customs also handles agricultural security, so you would not have further questions, e.g. if some regions of Spain have further restrictions, e.g. on food or a requirement to not stay on a farm for e.g. last 48 hours.

Things would be more complex if you stopped in e.g. Canada, you go out from the airport, and you bought something special.

In any case, do not worry (if you can speak some English). US immigration officers and custom officers are friendly and very talkative: if you have any question, just ask them: they are happy to talk. Just do not hide important information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP means immigration officer. Many people confuse those. Many immigration officers will ask this question , but customs officers rarely ask questions at all,

Comment: It make sense, but I get more question about "where are you from?" not the departure. But maybe it is more about me (Italian name, and a lot of immigration officers have Italian origin, so some small talk). But looking again the US custom form, it states "Countries visited on this trip prior to US arrival", which it is more clear question.